# Sampling a log-concave distribution using the adaptive rejection sampling method (R)

Tags: r, random, distribution, sampling

I am not very familiar with `R`. I have been trying to use the implementation of the [adaptive rejection sampling](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ars/versions/0.5/topics/ars) method in `R`, in order to sample from the following distribution:

[image]

here is my `R` code:

```
library(ars)
g1 <- function(x,r){(1./r)*((1-x)^r)}
f1 <- function(x,a,k) {
  add<-0
  for(i in 1:k) {
  add<- add+g1(x,i)
  }
  res <- (a* add)+(a-1)*log(x)+k*log(1-x)
  return(res)
}

g2 <- function(x,r){(1-x)^(r-1)}  
f1prima <- function(x,a,k) {
  add<-0
  for(i in 1:k) {
  add<- add-g2(x,i)
  }
  res <- (a* add)+(a-1)/x-k/(1-x)
  return(res)
}
mysample1<-ars(20,f1,f1prima,x=c(0.001,0.09),m=2,emax=128,lb=TRUE,xlb=0.0, ub=TRUE, xub=1,a=0.5,k=100)
```

The function is a **log-concave**, but I get different error messages when I run **ars** and fiddling around with the input parameters won't help here. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Well not completely but partially. which was putting the lower limit of **ars sampling** to *0.1* like this: `mysample1<-ars(n=2000, f1,f1prima,x=c(0.1,0.6),ns=100,lb=TRUE, xlb=0.1, m=2,a=0.85,k=500)`. I could not figure out why it works just with this condition or whether I can go to lower bounds as well?!!

Comment: ok, let me start writing something wrt the question, and maybe over next few days we'll get something

Answer (score 1):

First thing, which you already noticed is that your log-concave function is not very well defined at x=0 and x=1.0. So useful interval would be something like 0.01...0.99, not 0.0...1.0

Second, I don't like the idea to compute hundreds of terms in your summation term.
So, good idea might be to express it in following way, starting with derivative

S<sub>1</sub><sup>N-1</sup> q<sup>i</sup> is obviously [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) and could be replaced with 
(1-q<sup>N</sup>)/(1-q), where q=1-x.

This is derivative, so to get to similar term in function itself, just integrate it.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1-q%5EN)%2F(1-q)+dq will return [Gauss Hypergeometric function <sub>2</sub>F<sub>1</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) plus logarithm

-q<sup>N+1</sup> <sub>2</sub>F<sub>1</sub>(1, N+1; N+2; q)/(N+1) - log(1-q)

NB: It is the same integral as Beta before, but dealing with it was a bit more cumbersome
So, code to compute those terms:

```
library(gsl)
library(ars)
library(ggplot2)

Gauss2F1 <- function(a, b, c, x) {
    ifelse(x >= 0.0 & x < 1.0, hyperg_2F1(a, b, c, x), hyperg_2F1(c - a, b, c, 1.0 - 1.0/(1.0 - x))/(1.0 - x)^b)
}

f1sum <- function(x, N) {
    q <- 1.0 - x
    - q^(N+1) * Gauss2F1(1, N+1, N+2, q)/(N+1) - log(1.0 - q) 
}

f1sum.1 <- function(x, N) {
    q <- 1.0 - x
    res <- rep(0.0, length.out = length(x))
    s <- rep(1.0, length.out = length(x))
    for(k in 1:N) {
        s <- s * q / as.numeric(k)
        res <- res + s
    }
    res
}

f1 <- function(x, a, N) {
    a * f1sum(x, N) + (a - 1.0)*log(x) + N*log(1.0 - x)
}

f1.1 <- function(x, a, N) {
    a * f1sum.1(x, N) + (a - 1.0)*log(x) + N*log(1.0 - x)
}

f1primesum <- function(x, N) {
    q <- 1.0 - x
    (1.0 - q^N)/(1.0 - q)
}

f1primesum.1 <- function(x, N) {
    res <- rep(0.0, length.out = length(x))
    s <- rep(1.0, length.out = length(x))
    for(k in 1:N) {
        res <- res + s
        s <- s * q
    }
    -res
}

f1prime <- function(x, a, N) {
    a* f1primesum(x, N) + (a - 1.0)/x - N/(1.0 - x)
}

f1prime.1 <- function(x, a, N) {
    a* f1primesum.1(x, N) + (a - 1.0)/x - N/(1.0 - x)
}

p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = f1, args = list(0.5, 100), colour = "#4271AE") +
    stat_function(fun = f1.1, args = list(0.5, 100), colour = "#1F3552") +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "X", breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2), limits=c(0.001, 0.5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "F") +
    ggtitle("Log-concave function")
p
```

As you can see, I've implemented both versions - one using summation and another using analytical form of sums. Computed data for a=0.5, N=100.

First, there is a bit of a difference between direct sum and 2F1 - I attribute it to precision loss in summation.

Second, more important result - function is NOT log-concave. No questions why `ars()` if failing left and right. See graph below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried lower and upper bounds that you suggested for **ars sampling** but it returns error message. Regarding the original formalism, basically I am trying to implement [this paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/TehGorGha07.pdf) and the above equation refers to equation 25 in the paper, where `N` is not just a big number but it is the number of rows in the matrix `z`. Hence I do not know then expanding is a right way to deal with this equation

Comment: @Dalek please take a look at update and tell me what do you think

Comment: @ServerinPappadeux Sorry that I came back to this question after a while. I have a problem following the math and understanding how `sum_{i=1}^N (1/i)(1-x)^i` is converted to the geometric series? would you explain more?

Comment: @Dalek What we know is how to sum `\sum_{i=1}^N (q)^i, where q=1-x` - this is geometric series. What we have to do is to convert our sum to geometric - to do that, we DIFFERENTIATE it over `q`. After that series could be summed (lets denote ti `M(q)`), and we have now differential equation `dS(q)/dq = M(q)`. To get `S(q)` we just integrate, that's it. Integration will produce hypergeometric function. Please check all the math carefully.

Comment: @ServerinPappadeux so even using the approximation that you suggest, the function is not log-concave near zero, right? So ARS can be used for values near to zero?!! Did I understand it correctly? Is there any lower bound that it might work?

Comment: @Dalek function is not log-concave near zero. So you could try to find travelling from left to right the region where it is log-concave and try to sample from it. As far as I understood, you "real" case is even more complex, so writing code to check for log-concavity might be quite useful

Comment: Do you have any suggestion or is there any trick to deal with this numerical instability close to zero?